# Python, Keras - ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (10, 70, 1025) for Tensor u'dense_2_target:0', which has shape '(?, ?)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to train a RNN by batches.
The input input size
(10, 70, 3075),
where 10 is the batch size, 70 the time dimension, 3075 are the frequency dimension.

There are three outputs whose size is
(10, 70, 1025)
each, basically 10 spectrograms with size (70,1025).

I would like to train this RNN by regression, whose structure is

```
input_img = Input(shape=(70,3075 ) )
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(n_hid,return_sequences=True, dropout=0.5,    recurrent_dropout=0.2))(input_img)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(n_hid,  dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
o0 = ( Dense(1025, activation='sigmoid'))(x)
o1 = ( Dense(1025, activation='sigmoid'))(x)
o2 = ( Dense(1025, activation='sigmoid'))(x)
```

The problem is that output dense layers cannot take into account three dimensions, they want something like (None, 1025), which I don't know how to provide, unless I concatenate along the time dimension.

The following error occurs:

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (10, 70, 1025) for Tensor u'dense_2_target:0', which has shape '(?, ?)'

Would be the batch_shape option useful in the input layer? I have actually tried it, but I've got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance the second RNN is collapsing the sequence to a single vector because by default `return_sequences=False`. To make the model return sequences and run the Dense layer over each timestep separately just add `return_sequences=True` to the second RNN as well:

```
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(n_hid,  return_sequences=True, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.2))(x)
```

The Dense layers automatically apply to the last dimension so no need to reshape afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

To get the right output shape, you can use the Reshape layer:

```
o0 = Dense(70 * 1025, activation='sigmoid')(x)
o0 = Reshape((70, 1025)))(o0)
```

This will output (batch_dim, 70, 1025). You can do exactly the same for the other two outputs.